# R: Converting from string to double

Tags: r, string, double

I am trying to convert from a string to a double in R. However, every time I convert the number, R creates an integer.

For example:

```
a = "100.11"  
a = as.double(a)
```

And the output reads `100`. How to I retain the decimals when converting from string to numeric?
I've set `options(digits=3)`.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Have you tried `as.numeric(a)`?

Comment: @beginneR "as.double is a generic function. It is identical to as.numeric."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is the option you have set:

```
options(digits=3)
as.double("100.11")
#[1] 100
options(digits=5)
as.double("100.11")
#[1] 100.11
```

`digits` "controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values". You set the option to 3 and are shown 3 digits.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I thought it meant the number of digits after the decimal. Thanks!

Comment: What about `format(as.numeric("1244713607364931585"),digits=15)` which returns `#"1244713607364931584"`?